# Eclipse (Keplar) and Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, configure

I have an Eclipse workspace with a Web App  (lets call it MyApp), and Tomcat server. When I run MyApp, Tomcat finds default.jsp and the opening page displays

```
    http://localhost:8080/MyApp/Default.jsp?ActionPage=dashboard
```

- all fine and dandy.

This web page shows a menu.  I choose a menu option from this page which should render

```
    http://localhost:8080/MyApp/config.jsp,
```

and I get a HTTP Status 404 - /config.jsp   ... ie it is looking for the page at

```
    http://localhost:8080/config.jsp
```

and can't find it. Why is it looking there? It seems to have lost its context.

Netbeans doesn't exhibit this behaviour - it works fine.  I just don't know where to look for a solution. Is it the Tomcat configuration or the Web App configuration?

All suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

When you choose your menu option, how is the URL called : simple form submit, ajax request?
In any case, you should have a URL looking like `/MyApp/...` in your code.
You can also check which URLs are effectively called by using a debug tool in your browser (ie Firebug for Firefox)
Another test to do if you use a Tomcat embedded in Eclipse is to start your Tomcat outside from your IDE, just to check the potential behaviour differences.

Comment: Good point! I'll play with Firebug, and let you know if I get anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: After spending, I estimate, 2 days solid on this single problem, the solution found in

Comment: http://benhutchison.wordpress.com/2008/07/30/how-to-configure-tomcat-root-context/   provided the answer. Thanks for your help